# ACS Management Service on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, acs

Did anyone tried to use the Microsoft Access Control Service to use e.g. the Google/Yahoo or Facebook identity for authentication into Azure service from iOS?

I have found some [opensources](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/07/windows-azure-toolkit-for-ios-now-supports-the-access-control-service/) released by Microsoft, but I am interested in the developers experiences on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new video about this on channel 9 :
http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/iOS-Support-in-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services
Maybe that helps,
Willy